# Stateful Interprocess communication for Node.js

Tags: node.js, ipc

I may be missing an obvious trick here but...

Is there anyway for 2+ node.js processes to exchange messages in a stateful fashion?
As an example: 
process A is an HTTP server that fields incoming external http requests, to fulfil these requests it needs to get information from either process B or C. Currently I have 'A' opening a TCP/IP connection for each request to 'B' or 'C' which are listening on a suitable port.

This seems completely sucky and alot of overhead as each request requires lots of overhead to open a socket and close it, yet without opening a socket per request I cannot see a way to make sure that a response from the either 'B' or 'C' are bound to the correct HTTP response.

All processes are in nodejs, B + C have a long startup time (30+ seconds) so spawning them per request isn't an option. All processes are currently running on the same box (dual core).
In terms of protocol all I'm using is basic '[net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html)' server as described in the nodejs docs and throwing text across it.

Any suggestions etc gladly accepted

Comment: Why can't process A just maintain persistent TCP connections to processes B + C and use them as needed?

Comment: If i send a data down the pipe, when a response comes back how do I . nodejs know which http request to apply that data to? (I genuinely don't know)

Comment: It depends on the protocol being spoken by the servers B and C.  Can you update your question with details about that?

Comment: Added a little more - let me know if that isn't enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose to pass a unique session ID (app server/self generated) as part of your messages (between processes A <-> B/C) & perhaps append a counter to the session ID (with a delimiter  between the session ID and the counter) to keep track of requests.  The counter would increment on each new request.  I am sure there may be better/simpler options that you could avail.

For inter-process message transfer, one could look at in-memory caches (e.g. redis/memcached etc.) or use messaging servers such as ZermoMQ/RabbitMQ etc (you could use Redis for queue/pub-sub messaging as well).  You could also choose to avoid messaging servers & simply use hook.io or net/tcp within node for message transfer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I was being a bit dim and didn't think I could stash the http connections in a pool to dealt with later.